# Array filter by array of array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have sample data

```
[{
    "section": "RADIOGRAPHY",
    "sub_type": "ABDOMEN & PELVIS",
    "list": [{
        "item": "Abdomen",
      },
      {
        "item": "Abdomen/Pelvis"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "section": "SCANNING",
    "sub_type": "ABDOMEN & PELVIS",
    "list": [{
        "item": "first",
      },
      {
        "item": "second"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to filter the deep array like if I search by `list item name` it should match **likely**

if I search with `fir` it should return matched object to that condition but it is not woking

```
 let temp = this.name.map(function(ele){
    return ele.list.filter(el => {
      return el['item'].includes(`${value}`)
    })
  });
  console.log(temp);
```

Comment: `likely` isn't in your sample json, can you clarify what your data actually looks like

Comment: @Phix match any three characters with list item name

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter instead of map, and in the second find uset find

```
const temp = name.filter(function(ele){
    return ele.list.find(el => {
      return el['item'].includes(`fir`)
    })
  });
```

Comment: you answer is giving empty array

Comment: you are changing the name of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking like this?

```js
let arr = [
    {
    "section": "RADIOGRAPHY",
    "sub_type": "ABDOMEN & PELVIS",
    "list": [{
      "item": "Abdomen",
    },
    {
      "item": "Abdomen/Pelvis"
    }
    ]},
    {
    "section": "SCANNING",
    "sub_type": "ABDOMEN & PELVIS",
    "list": [{
      "item": "first",
    },
    {
      "item": "second"
    }
    ]}
]
let toSearch = 'Abd'; 

let array = arr.map(a=>a.list).flat().filter(o => o.item.includes(toSearch));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
let tmp = this.name.map( ele => ele.list.filter(el => el.item.includes(`${value}`)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Try this out.

```
let input = "fir";
let temp = [];
arr.forEach(item => item.list.forEach( e => e.item.search(input.trim()) > -1 ? temp.push(e) : ""));

console.log(temp);
```

Output of this will be:

```
[ { item: 'first' } ]
```